# Oracle 19c Silent Installation problems

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I am installing Oracle 19c database in silent mode with an built-in account. The directory I am creating is located on my drive and it's called "Oracle19c". The installation passed successfully, and the Oracle database was installed successfully, and the user for the Oracle base is "NT Authority\System".

Then I want to install appropriate version of ODAC for this Oracle 19c database. I'd like to also use the silent install mode with an built-in account, but there is a problem `[INS-32104] Specified Oracle Home user is not the owner of the specified Oracle Base.` Everything probably would be okay, but the ODAC uses 
NT Authority\Local Service".

Does any one faced similar problem? How to deal with it, I would like to have both in same oracle base directory, as the database is under "dbhome_1" and the ODAC would be  under "client_1" sharing the same "Oracle19c" oracle base directory.

Is there a way how to ignore this priviliges to this oracle base directory, because this problem seems to be since oracle 18c, or the only solution how to deal with it, is to create an "orainstall" user which will be a part of "ora_install" group, and use this user for both installations?

Comment: I guess you use the OUI (Oracle Universal Installer) - You can select component ODBC, OLE DB or whatever you require, then you don't need a separate installation.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit what do you exactly mean? I am installing separately oracle server, and ODBC 19c. Could you explain your minds?

Comment: The oracle servers includes always also the client. How do you run the database installation? Which parts from ODAC do you need?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am installing Oracle Server in silent mode and I am installing only the software. The ODAC is needed for me as I want to be able to connect to the database from different machine using the tnsnames.ora and listener.ora

Comment: Again, how do you run the installation? Please provide the command you execute. If you like to connect from different machine to your database then you don't need ODAC at all (nevertheless it might be included already)